# DXA Java render embedded image in RTF

Tags: dxa, java, dxa-1.4

When creating content in a RTF field you have the option to insert tables and images. An Image is added to the RTF field with a fixed with of 100%. How can we manipulate that ?

```
<p>
  <img src="tcm:30-1737" title="320x198" alt="320x198" class="pull-left"/>
  Lorem Ipsum dollar - met nog meer content :)
</p>
```

Output in HTML

```
<img src="/media/320x198_tcm30-1737_w1024_n.png" alt="320x198" data-aspect="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: I would expect there is actually a bit more HTML outputted for that single image, since when I look in the [article view](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/develop/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/Article.jsp#L43) there should be a `<figure>` tag around it too? but I have a feeling this is a defect where DXA fails to support the left, right and center alignment of images in an article RTF as mentioned in the [whitelabel HTML design](http://sdl.github.io/dxa-html-design/content-types/complex-article.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is currently logged as a defect https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/41 (issue is available in both Java and .NET versions DXA), and we are looking at solving it in the upcoming 1.5 release (but no promises currently about that).

Comment: It's solved in the 1.5 development branch

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for (embedded) Images is rendered by the (Core) Image View, so that is where it can be modified.
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/Image.jsp

Note that the Image View Model has a property which indicates whether it's embedded in Rich Text or not. This can be used in the View to render different HTML if needed. See, for example:
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/YouTubeVideo.jsp